# SQL Query speed and refinement

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, paypal

So I have just set up a database which holds only one table with the following fields:

key_value:  holds 6 digit code for a key

redeemed: boolean for if the key is redeemed

redeemed_by: who redeemed it

redeemed_date: when it was redeemed

software_name: name of the software the key relates to

I basically start with an empty database and then when someone purchases through PayPal, they get their own key and it is added to the database. After this they open an app which lets them input their code which is then searched for in the database and marked as redeemed so it can't be used again - this results in both redeemed and unredeemed codes being in one table.

If I was to reach a good few thousand purchases, would this cause the database to slow down majorly, crash maybe? what if it was a bigger number, say 10,000?

What exactly would be a good solution for this, even if I had another table of redeemed keys, it would have to look in the redeemed table to see if it was redeemed?

Thanks for any answer, I am still learning databases and SQL!

Comment: if your mysql has problems with 10,000 records, you're running it on a massively overloaded and/or underpowered machine. there's mysql instances with literally billions of records in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your design is sound.  You might want to add indexes based on what queries you will be running.  key_value sounds like a good primary key which would also serve as an index for updating redeemed.

As noted by Marc B, the hardware is your only likely consideration for performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two tables for this:  One for what you have spec'ed out, but another as an archive table with a job that migrates over redeemed/expired records on a regular basis.

Reasoning:  The primary purpose of the table is for the benefit of redemptions, not for use as an archive.  Over time, as more and more redeemed records are found in the table, the performance for lookups of unredeemed records starts getting worse and worse because of all the "deadwood" in the table.  (Do you think eBay houses all active and completed auctions in one table?)

If you still absolutely need a "one-table" solution, you can easily create a view that merges the two tables.

Also, if you set up a proper primary key, the performance (for a while) will not degrade quickly as that would eliminate table scans which is what you are alluding to when the record volumes grow.